# How to update ms access database table using update and sum() function?

Tags: sql

I have Two tables in my access database

- table1(ID,productname,qunatity,remainder)
- table2(ID,productname,sales)

these tables are related together using "product name" ,How can I update"reminder" from table1 with the value of "quantity form first table - Sum(sales) from second table"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because update queries in MS Access require [updateable](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html) status, you cannot use a direct inner join on an aggregate query. Consider using the MS Access [DSum()](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dsum.php) function:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.remainder = table1.quantity - 
    DSum("Sales", "table2", "ProductName='" & table1.ProductName & "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform an update join by getting the `SUM()` first like

```
UPDATE a 
SET    a.remainder = x.SaleTotal
FROM   table1 a 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT productname, SUM(sales) AS SaleTotal 
                   FROM TABLE2 GROUP BY productname) x 
       ON a.productname = x.productname;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say that it's linked by the productname field please tell me in table 1 that is a foreign key. Since you already have an ID in table 2 there's no reason not to use that ID as the foreign key in table 1.

If you were to do that the update would be as simple as this:

```
update table1 
set table1.quantity = table1.quantity - SUM( table2.sales ) 
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.productID = table2.productID
where table1.productID = 1;
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer ..I didn't use ID becuase the database conatins many tables not just Two and I need to use Productname to create relationship,but in order to simplify my question I just used Two Tables....Accept my regards