# Not updatable query - Access

Tags: ms-access

This should be a simple query - I have read through several other posts, but can't figure out how to integrate their solutions into my query.

[image: Access Qry View]

```
UPDATE Items_tbl 
   SET Items_tbl.ITEM_QTY_ONHAND = 
      (SELECT Sum([Item_Locations_tbl]![ITEMLOC_QTY_ONHAND])
 FROM [Item_Locations_tbl]
 WHERE  Items_tbl.ITEM_ID =Item_Locations_tbl.ITEMLOC_LOC_ID);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update ms access database table using update and sum() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465036/update-ms-access-database-table-using-update-and-sum-function)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: "Operation must use an updateable query" - MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53792465/error-operation-must-use-an-updateable-query-ms-access)

Answer (score 0):

The query is not updateable because you are using an aggregate function (specifically, `sum`).

You can avoid this by instead using a domain aggregate function, such as `DSum`, e.g.:

```sql
update items_tbl
set items_tbl.item_qty_onhand = 
dsum("itemloc_qty_onhand", "item_locations_tbl", "itemloc_loc_id = " & items_tbl.item_id)
```

Note that the above assumes that your `itemloc_loc_id` field is **numerical**; if this field is string-valued, then you will need to surround the criteria with single-quotes, e.g.:

```sql
update items_tbl
set items_tbl.item_qty_onhand = 
dsum("itemloc_qty_onhand","item_locations_tbl","itemloc_loc_id = '" & items_tbl.item_id & "'")
```

An alternative way to circumvent the restriction of the inability to use aggregate functions in an `UPDATE` query is to generate a temporary table to store the value of the sum for each record, and then update your table using the values held by the temporary table.

Comment: Thanks Lee,  Evidently this was answered elsewhere, but I really appreciate you replying to the post.  
I apologize for the duplicate post